# How to get information horizontally in Report footer

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-8.5

I have a field which contains multiple information.
when i place this filed in details section, I am getting information like this:

```
Product Code
ABC
CBD
FDB
```

How to get this same information horizontally in the report footer like this
Product codes are ABC,CBD,FDB

Is it possible to get this  using formula??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your requirements, it may work:

1. Create a subreport and put it on report footer.
2. Put product code in subreport details sections.
3. Use section export to "format with multiple columns" (the details section).
4. Set an appropriate column width and mark "across then down".

Comment: I have created a sub report & using Sql query got the desired output as I needed..anyway that's for your valuable response